# Render multiple query result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my HTML page, I need to show the total number of items bought this day and below I have to display all the datas. Its a simple thing but I am not sure how to do it in NodeJS.

I am trying following code:

### index.js

```
var HL = require('../modules/history-list');

app.get('/activity', function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.user == null) {
        res.redirect('/');
    } else {
        HL.getTotalRecords(function (e, count) {
            res.render('activity', {
                title: 'My Activity',
                udata: req.session.user, 
                count: count
            });
        });

        HL.getAllRecords(function (e, activities) {
            res.render('activity', {
                title: 'My Activity',
                udata: req.session.user, 
                activities: activities
            });
        });
    }
});
```

### history-list.js

```
exports.getTotalRecords = function (callback) {
    let start = moment().startOf('day');
    let end = moment().endOf('day');

    history.aggregate([{
            "$addFields": {
                "date": {
                    "$dateFromString": {
                        "dateString": "$date"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "date": {
                    "$gte": start.toDate(),
                    "$lt": end.toDate()
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$count": "count"
        }
    ]).toArray(function (e, res) {
        if (e) callback(e)
        else callback(null, res);
    });
}

exports.getAllRecords = function (callback) {
    history.find({}, function (e, res) {
        if (e) callback(e)
        else callback(null, res);
    });

}
```

I am getting `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` error as I have res.render twice. I am not sure how can I fix it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: It happens because you call another `res.render` after already rendering your `totalRecords`. You might want your `getTotalRecords` and `getAllRecords` to return proper records, store them in some collection, then render both at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var HL = require('../modules/history-list');

app.get('/activity', function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.user == null) {
        res.redirect('/');
    } else {
        HL.getTotalRecords(function (e, count) {
            HL.getAllRecords(function (e, activities) {
                res.render('activity', {
                    title: 'My Activity',
                    udata: req.session.user,
                    count: count,
                    activities: activities
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```